# AWS Secret Manager secret deleted without mandatory retention period

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I created a secret using CloudFormation template that looked like this:

```
  "DBSecretCredentials": {
     "Type": "AWS::SecretsManager::Secret",
     "Properties": {
        "Name": "MyAwesomeSecret",
        "Description": "Something,
        "GenerateSecretString": {
           "SecretStringTemplate": "{\"USER\":\"superman\"}",
           "GenerateStringKey": "PASSWORD",
           "PasswordLength": 30,
           "ExcludeCharacters": "\"@/\\"
        },
        "Tags": [
           {
              "Key": "AppName",
              "Value": "Something"
           },
           {
              "Key": "Environment",
              "Value": {
                 "Ref": "Environment"
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  }
```

When I deleted CloudFormation stack, I was expecting the secret to be there in "pending deletion" status with 7 days retention policy as that is what AWS mandates.

When I visited AWS Console, there was no secret with pending deletion mode. (Yes, i clicked on gear icon and checked "Show secrets scheduled for deletion" checkbox.

I queried `AWS Secrets Manager` using CLI to list all the secrets but it did not return the secret that was deleted as a result of CFT Stack deletion.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a CloudFormation stack is deleted, Secrets Manager is called with the "force-delete-without-recovery" option and all secrets are deleted permanently. This is to enable CloudFormation to be able to delete each referenced secret without leaving artifacts in your account.

Comment: Reference: [AWS Developer Forums: Secrets Manager and CF- can not create ...](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=884266&tstart=0)